# Why is my Ubuntu build laggy when moving windows?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have the following system:

i5 6400 skylake processor @2.7ghz quad
Amd Radeon r9 380 4gb gddr5
8gigs of ram ddr4.
250gb Samsung 850 pro ssd

I am trying to run Ubuntu and Xubuntu for that matter @4K 60hz, that resolution runs fine on the host which is a Windows 10 pc. Once I get into the virtual machine however, the windows lag extensively during movements, leading me to question if I’m deficient in ram, graphics or processing power, or a combination of the three. The menu that displays the apps takes upwards of 8 seconds to display said apps, and it makes the experience seem laggy.

I have tried multiple combinations of cores and ram allowances between host and guest systems... and it doesn’t seem to solve the problem.

Any advice so that I may achieve a “seamless” lag free Virtual machine displaying 4K @ 60hz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, my hardware proved to be too weak to run a virtual machine without any input lag. Therefore I implemented a separate partition on my SSD, and Ubuntu now works perfectly... runs faster than even windows or my macOS systems.
Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I cannot get it how can SSD drive help to run graphics (mouse) more smoothly inside a virtual machine, it can't get faster than host os, it can be your impression though. SSD helps a lot with files, but lagging mouse? doesn't sound much logical or does it. I just wonder if you havent done also something else alongside that you forgot. I never experienced that due to SSD, I had to allow VMSVGA  graphics emulator regime after reinstalling GuestAdditions to make the GuestAddition again take into consideration my new graphics card, just sayin..

Answer (score 2):

You didnt mention what virtual machine software you are using.  More than likely running the virtual machine at 4K resolution is using all the video memory assigned to it.  If possible, assign more video memory.  Depending on your hypervisor, you can try enabling/disabling 2D/3D acceleration to find an optimal setting.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issues in XFCE with very slow window moving & resizing, when not using a discrete video card (onboard video). It's likely related to your virtualization software & hardware integration, as Keltari mentions. Try running [X]Ubuntu directly (outside of Windows, without virtualization) to get an idea of the "best case scenario" performance.

Enabling display compositing should help, though it uses a little more resources. It's in Settings, Window Manager Tweaks, Compositor:

[image]

A workaround is to hide the contents of windows when moving & resizing them. Strangely, if using display compositing, then hiding window contents when resizing again makes it very slow (at least for me). In XFCE it's in the red box in the Window Manager settings:

[image]